# Escape $ when using add_custom_command with CMake/Ninja

Tags: c++, cmake, ninja

```
add_custom_target(target1)

add_custom_command(TARGET target1
    COMMAND echo $1222
    COMMAND echo $$1222
)
```

If the custom commmand contains dollar sign, Ninja will treat it as a phony rule.

Comment: possibly related: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/18062

Comment: have you tried `COMMAND echo [[$1222]]` ?

Answer (score 0):

From https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html :

> VERBATIM
>
> All arguments to the commands will be escaped properly for the build tool so that the invoked command receives each argument
> unchanged. Note that one level of escapes is still used by the CMake
> language processor before add_custom_command even sees the arguments.
> Use of VERBATIM is recommended as it enables correct behavior. When
> VERBATIM is not given the behavior is platform specific because there
> is no protection of tool-specific special characters.

Comment: Still doesn't work.